# Entity Framework error updating iSeries record

Tags: entity-framework, db2, ibm-midrange

I am new to iSeries AS/400.  I've downloaded DB2Connect from IBM and I'm trying to get Entity Framework to work with it.

I have been successful in creating my EDMX file from the iSeries and I can read records.  However, whenever I try and save a change, I get the error message

```
ERROR [55019] [IBM][AS] SQL7008N  REXX variable \"INVENTORY \" contains inconsistent data.
```

From what I've read, this has to do with the table not being journalled.  I don't have control over whether it is or not.  I assume there is some kind of setting in the connection string that I need to set, but I can't figure out what.

My current EF connection string is (user and password removed)

```
<add name="LATHAM1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=IBM.Data.DB2;provider connection string=&quot;Database=LATHAM1;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Server=LATHDEV1:446;Persist Security Info=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If I attempt to update using just ADO.Net, I can update this just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you add `CommitMode=0` as per [Connection string keywords - Server properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikconnstrkeywordsservprop.htm)
.

I usually just add the journaling.